# Unable to display twitter bootstrap modal after ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show modal window on click of link but also want to do ajax request to get the object which needs to be shown on modal window.

I am getting response with the content which needs to be shown on modal window but it is not popping up as modal window probably the script is not getting executed.

Code

**Main Page**

```
  <%= link_to "New Topic", "#", :class => 'btn primary float-right bootstrap-popover'   %>
  <div id="modal_form_container"></div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
   $('a.bootstrap-popover').live('click',  function(){
   $(this).unbind('click');

   $.ajax({
          url: "/topics/new",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "html",


          complete: function() {
            $('loading').hide();
          },

     success: function(data) {

     },

     error:function() {
        }
      }); // End of Ajax
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#modal_form_container').html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => 'new_form')%>");   
$('#modal_form').modal('show');
```

This new_form page contains content to be shown on modal window

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the loading element is not being hidden?

```
$('loading').hide();
```

Should this not be something like:

```
$('#loading').hide();
```

Comment: No still it doesnot work. Basically I want to know how to load twitter bootstrap modal window after ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write something like following code after your ajax request gets success.

```
$('#PopupBoxId').modal('show');      // Show the pop-up (modal)
$('#disable_layer').modal('show');   // Show the black overlay
```

We have to manually show the pop-up after the ajax request handling.. As per my small experience in bootstrap.
:)

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [Bootstrap Modal Manager](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal)? You can use it like so:

```
$("a.open-with-ajax-loader").live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body').modalmanager('loading');
  $('#id-of-modal-div').modal({
    remote: '/url/to/load'
  });
});
```

You can see this in action on the [live demo page](http://jschr.github.com/bootstrap-modal/) for the Bootstrap Modal Manager ( scroll down a bit, look for the AJAX demo ).